# Can the output of plt.imshow() be converted to a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

My intention is to use matplotlib to convert a coloured image into a grayscale image and use colormap to display it in the Viridis scale.

The code for that is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

IMG = mpimg.imread('dog_1.jpg')

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

   
gray = rgb2gray(IMG)    
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

The output displayed is proper and as follows:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppobS.png)

Now, I want to save the output image in a variable as a numpy array to carry out further processing. Can I do it in any way?

Comment: Do you want the axes in there as well, or are you just looking to apply the color map to your image? There are simple ways to apply a color map, you don't need `imshow` for that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sir, I am able to apply colour map without using `imshow` now, thanks to your input, but now I wish to know how I can replicate the effect of `vmin` and `vmax` inside `imshow` as asked in the comment in the answer below.

Comment: I'm guessing the easiest way is to scale the image: `(img - vmin) * (255 / (vmax - vmin))` should give you an array with values between 0 and 255 that match the 256 colormap entries in viridis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.imread()` returns a 3-dimensional numpy array with RGB layers. Your `rgb2gray()` function returns a 2-dimensional numpy array with a grayscale image. There is no need to extract a numpy array from the object returned by `plt.imshow()` when you have two numpy arrays with the image data already. However, if you insist in doing it, you can try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

IMG = mpimg.imread('img.jpg')

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])


gray = rgb2gray(IMG)    
aximg = plt.imshow(gray, cmap='viridis')

# an array with RGBA data of the image produced by plt.imshow 
arr = aximg.make_image(renderer=None, unsampled=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you kindly tell me what should I do if I have to save the exact image (without axes) in a variable [as a 3d matrix] as displayed by `plt.imshow(Img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin = 0.55, vmax = 0.80)` ? How would the code given by you be modified in that case?